# Using unity Rigidbody 2D gravity, how to add to velocity?

Tags: unity, 2d, physics

I am creating a top-down game, and have an object I want to create a small bouncy illusion for. Since I dont have anything to collide with I'll have to do it with Scripts.

Without Unity I would probably do something like:

```
function fall ()
{
    this.vertical_speed = this.vertical_speed + GRAVITY;
    if (this.vertical_speed > TERMINAL_VELOCITY)
    {
        this.vertical_speed = TERMINAL_VELOCITY;
    }
    this.vertical_position = this.vertical_position - this.vertical_speed;
}
```

However in Unity we have the `Rigidbody 2D`, so I want to somehow use that for this.

if I set `rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(1, 0) * speed * delta;`, it gets a constant speed, and ignores gravity. How can I add gravity?

i.e: I want to create a curve like:
[image]

Comment: You're asking quite a few questions at the end there. Besides that, you are doing new Vector2(1,0) where 0 is Y so whatever Y velocity there is will just be 0, so gravity won't impact it. IIRC

Comment: Didn't even think about that, only 1 question now. Also, I know what I am doing wrong, I just dont know how to do it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preserve the existing vertical (ie. Y) movement. That is, when you create the vector to assign, use the existing velocity.y for the y component of the vector, and only create a new x component.

Comment: Thanks, using this I get gravity. However I would like it to go up (y+) first, then start going down. Like a curve, this just goes down :)

Comment: Don't try to control the Y velocity directly in that case. Instead apply an upward impulse ie. Rigidbody2D.AddForce() with force mode set to "impulse" for a sudden jolt https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode2D.Impulse.html

Comment: cool, Ill try this

Comment: This works. For future readers; Dont be stupid and put it in the update loop like me, call it only once!

Comment: or put it in the update loop but with a condition so it doesn't trigger every frame; that's how I do a jump command

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gravity on the rigidbody and also setting the rigidbody using new Vector2 then just add the current velocity y to it

```
new Vector2(1, rigidBody.velocity.y);
```

Comment: Thanks, using this I get gravity. However I would like it to go up (y+) first, then start going down. Like a curve, this just goes down :)

Comment: Yes :) That sounds like it